# Apply function to a dataframe which utilises means of columns (~ Pareto scaling)

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

In a dataframe, I want to divide each value by the square root of the standard deviation of the column's value (~ Pareto Scaling). I have taken the code from existing package (https://github.com/cran/RFmarkerDetector/blob/master/R/scaling.R)

```
paretoscale <- function(data) {
    # Here we perform centering
    x.centered <- apply(x, 2, function(x) x - mean(x))
    # Then we perform scaling on the mean-centered matrix
    x.sc <- apply(x.centered, 2, function(x) x/sqrt(sd(x)))
    x.sc <- cbind(sample_classes, x.sc)
```

Does `x.centered <- apply(x, 2, function(x) x - mean(x)` does `x - mean(column where x is)` as it should? Could you please explain how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable names may be a bit unpedagogical, especially for a novice. Let's rewrite the `apply` part so not to confuse the reader.

```
paretoscale <- function(data) {
    # Here we perform centering
    x.centered <- apply(x, 2, function(col) col - mean(col))
    # Then we perform scaling on the mean-centered matrix
    x.sc <- apply(x.centered, 2, function(col) col/sqrt(sd(col)))
    x.sc <- cbind(sample_classes, x.sc)
```

What `apply(x, 2, function(col) col - mean(col))` does is it runs on object `x` (a data.frame or a matrix) column-wise. For each column, it finds its mean and substracts it for each element.

Here is how `apply` works in comparison with a `for` loop.

```
xy <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, ncol = 3))

apply(X = xy, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(col) col - mean(col))

     X1 X2 X3
[1,] -1 -1 -1
[2,]  0  0  0
[3,]  1  1  1

# Create an empty object
newxy <- xy
newxy[] <- NA

# Work column-wise
for (i in 1:ncol(xy)) {
  col <- xy[, i]
  # Calculate mean and substract it from all elements of the column
  newxy[, i] <- col - mean(col)
}
newxy

  X1 X2 X3
1 -1 -1 -1
2  0  0  0
3  1  1  1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
So in
_x.centered <- apply(x, 2, function(x) x - mean(x))_ first 'x' refers to the elements of the dataframe, but in 'function(x) x - mean(x)' x actually addresses the whole columns already? (Because it is an argument of apply function?)